# How to run the post_save signal after a specified time?

Tags: python, django, django-signals

There is a `post_save` signal. Need to run it no earlier than an hour after the creation of the object.

I can use `time.sleep(3600)`, but this is not the best approach, as I understand it.

What other options are there?

Comment: You can use celery, maybe.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. But I never worked with `celery`. I'd love to deal with him, of course. Can someone give an example on this simple little problem?